# how to pass a variable to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

**index.php**

```
$typesql = $_GET['type']
```

**fetch_pages.php**

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?);

$results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($name, $type);
```

I use the above to get the artist type in index.php, I want to pass it to use it in fetch.php and bind it to my sql query.

Comment: use query string to pass value from one page to another.
like http://localhost/fetch.php?type=<your value>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the $_GET value to a session and you can use that session  variable to access the data on another page

example
 
**page 1**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['type']=$_GET['type'];
```

**page 2**

```
session_start();
$type = $_SESSION['type'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Data can be passed to the next page in various ways. You can pass variable to next page by following ways

1. Session
2. Cookie
3. Url Variable

But in your case using session is the right way.

**index.php**

```
session_start(); 
$typesql = $_GET["type"];
$_SESSION["typesql"] = $typesql;
```

**fetch_pages.php**

```
session_start();
$typesql = $_SESSION["typesql"]; 

$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, type FROM artists WHERE type = ?);

$results->bind_param("s", $typesql);
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($name, $type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any params through url query(but the length of url is limited).

In `index.php`

```
<a href="/fetch_pages.php?type=<?=$typesql?>">fetch pages</a>
```

In `fetch pages.php`

```
// get type from url
$typesql = $_GET['type'];
// and then bind it to sql.
```